# C# Replace Everything before the first Space

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I need to remove everything in a string before the first occurrence of a space.

1. Every string starts with a number and followed by a space
2. Replace the number and the space, thus leaving the rest of the string in tact

**For Example:**

> 22 The cats of India
>
> 4 Royal Highness
>
> 562 Eating Potatoes
>
> 42 Biscuits in the 2nd fridge
>
> 2564 Niagara Falls at 2 PM

I just need:

> The cats of India
>
> Royal Highness
>
> Eating Potatoes
>
> Biscuits in the 2nd fridge
>
> Niagara Falls at 2 PM

**Basically remove every number before the first space, including the first space.**

**I tried this:**

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
       string newline = line.Trim().Remove(0, line.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
}
```

This works for numbers below 10. After it hits 2 digits, it doesn't work properly.

How should I change my code?

Comment: Earthling, many have answered your initial question. You have now commented with an additional question. That is not how SO works. If you have another question please open another one.

Comment: And do not forget to upvote those that were helpful.

Comment: If the inputs are known to be in said format, using a regex for this case is, IMO, overkill: `string.Concat(str.TrimStart().SkipWhile(char.IsNumber).Skip(1))`. Ask yourself if you want to Google what `\p{Zs}` means every time you have to change this code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure you only match digits at the beginning of the string, you can use the following regex:

```
^\d+\p{Zs}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP8aZ8/2)

Declare it like:

```
public static readonly Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\d+\p{Zs}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

The `^\d+\p{Zs}` regex means: one or more digits at the start of the string followed with 1 whitespace.

And then use it like

```
string newline = rx.Replace(line, string.Empty);
```

**EDIT**: To make sure the `line` has no leading whitespace, we can add `.Trim()` to strip it like:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\d+\p{Zs}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string newline = rx.Replace(line.Trim(), string.Empty);
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much! I have added a slight change as well. I added line.Trim() to make it work/ Thanks man!

Comment: Aha, you still can use `^\p{Zs}*\d+\p{Zs}` if you just need to remove *leading* whitespace, but in case you will still need to trim the whitespace from the end of `line`, you can really make use of the `Trim()`.

Answer (score 2):

I know you already found a resolution to your issue.  But I am going to explain why your code didn't work in the first place.

[image: Your Code]

Your data has extra spaces which is why you are trimming it: `line.Trim()`. But the real problem lies in the the following statement:

```
string newline = line.Trim().Remove(0, line.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

You are making the assumption about the order of the operation and the fact that `string` data type is not [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). When the operation of `Trim()` function is complete it returns a whole new string which is used in the `Remove()` operation.  But the `IndexOf()` function is done on the original line of data.

So the correct line of code would be the following:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // trim the line first
    var temp = line.Trim();

    // now perform all operation on the new temporary string
    string newline = temp.Remove(0, temp.IndexOf(' ') + 1);

    // debugging purpose
    Console.WriteLine(newline);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
var lines = new string[]
    {
        "22 The cats of India",
        "4 Royal Highness",
        "562 Eating Potatoes",
        "42 Biscuits in the 2nd fridge",
        "2564 Niagara Falls at 2 PM"
    };

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var newLine = string.Join(" ", line.Split(' ').Skip(1));
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will, but the question was about a specific input :) "Every string starts with a number and followed by a space"

Comment: One cannot be too sure of the input quality (I am working in the localization industry) :).

Comment: I completely agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like so:

```
string newline = Regex.Replace(line, @"^\s*\d+\s*", "");
```

This will remove numbers only, not other text before the first space.

Comment: EDIT: What if I need all the numbers after the first space. I need to replace the numbers and the first space only

Comment: @Earthling Why don't you try the responses provided? My regex is anchored to the beginning of the string, so that it only takes numbers at the beginning!

Comment: It will also match spaces if any at the beginning of the string, and also will match if there is a digit without a space after it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, I assumed that this was intended as behavior because the original example had a `Trim()` call. Also "any digit before the first space" is not clearly specified for the no-space-case; I assumed "any digit" to be the essential part and that the result string shall be left trimmed.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
       string newline = line.Replace(line.Split(new Char[]{' '})[0] + ' ',string.Empty);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
string search=line.Split(new Char[]{' '})[0];
int pos=line.indexOf(search);
string newline = line.Substring(0, pos) + string.Empty + line.Substring(pos + search.Length);
```

**FULL CODE**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lines = new string[]
        {
            "22 The cats of India",
            "4 Royal Highness",
            "562 Eating Potatoes",
            "42 Biscuits in the 2nd fridge",
            "2 Niagara Falls at 2 PM"
        };
        foreach(string line in lines){
            string search=line.Split(new Char[]{' '})[0];
            int pos=line.IndexOf(search);
            string newline = line.Substring(0, pos) + string.Empty + line.Substring(pos + search.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(newline);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but it seems that this code doesn't compile, it seems difficult to understand, and if a second occurence of the number is found later in the string it would clear that out as well.

Comment: This code is working fine, I have updated the code. `Split` is added instead of `split`. Its working fine on a fiddle.

Comment: Still if you have "1 Banana 1 Fruit" as string the result will be "Banana Fruit" instead of "Banana 1 Fruit" as asked by the OP.

Comment: @Lucero @Earthling I have updated my code and added a full code, its working fine now.`1 Banana 1 Fruit` will be `Banana 1 Fruit`

Comment: Well, apart from being *very* inefficient, it will still remove not only numbers but anything before the first space. Also there are edge cases that don't really work - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/JTUvRF ;)